# PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size - on a non-existent line

Tags: php, memory

I'm seeing this error in my production server, sometimes (I mean, it seems random, as my site as a decent traffic and so far it just happened 5 times):

> > [21-Feb-2012 23:43:19 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 261900 bytes) in /home/xxxxx/xxxxx/xxx.php on line 1811

The funny part is, **the file has only 798 lines**, and this never happened before to me.
It may have to do with recent changes I made to my scripts, yes, but this error simply doesn't make sense to me.

Please keep in mind that I know what "Allowed memory size exhausted" error means, and I know how to increase the memory limit.
However, my question here is, **why is PHP referring to a line that doesn't exist?**
I don't know how to fix this problem, because this makes no sense to me.

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe its including a file and that file is failing. And also the server might be doing something like an autoload or something of the sort.

Comment: Was the old /home/xxxxx/xxxxx/xxx.php longer and do you have some sort of opcode cache?

Comment: It would help if we could see a little of the code from the file in question.

Comment: @jakx - It's including many files. What do you mean with "failing"? If the memory problem was on that included file, it would make sense the error to refer to that file, am I right? And what do you mean with "autoload"?

Comment: Long shot: Check the modified date on that particular file to see if it's been altered

Comment: @EugenRieck - I do not use any opcode cache. All I use is Memcache and suPHP. Thank you.

Comment: @MikeB - It has been altered, yes. I made changes on it, but I don't see what I could have done to affect memory on a "non-existent" line.

Comment: Well can you do prints in the includes like print a 1 before the start of the script and then print a 1 at the end, and do that for every script, and then when it fails the last number you saw is the one it failed on.

Comment: @Mike - The file is long, and my scripts are very "complex" to show here. I would show a little of the code, if the line existed :)

Comment: No, I'm saying that the file was atleast 1811 lines long at one point when it generated the error. Then it was altered back down to its original size for whatever reason.

Comment: @jakx - Yeah, that would be the first thing I would do now if the error happened *everytime*. The thing here is, it seems very random. Thank you for the hints.

Comment: @MikeB - Ah ok, that is not happening for sure. I guarantee that. Thank you.

Comment: is there anyway you can get the stack trace? click view stack trace or turn on better errors?

Comment: Well you're not the only one (old question, no accepted answer) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1813360/php-fatal-error-on-line-number-that-doesnt-exist

Comment: @jakx - I use `debug_backtrace()` on `set_error_handler()` to make the stack trace, but it doesn't seem giving any trace for this Fatal Error. It usually does on Warnings and other errors.

Comment: @MikeB - Nice hints there. I'll try to check my recent changes, and see if there is some large array being created or too many objects, etc.

Comment: Hey all of you! Please read my answer bellow. Thank you for all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just found what was causing this memory leak.

It was a recent change that was entering in recursion cycle between two functions, although it was a rare event.

The line 1811 is real, yes, but the file that the error was referring is not correct. The line 1811 was from another file (included on that referred one) where one of the functions is.

I still appreciate the help from the people who commented above.

Comment: Just had the same thing. In my case, lib A calls lib B (recursively, till it runs out of memory, which was the bug). But PHP reported the memory error using the line number from lib A, but the file path to lib B (which doesn't have that many lines). Very confusing. Thanks for your tip.

Comment: I'm very glad this was helpful to you!